# Initialization of static constexpr class member dependent on template argument type

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, constexpr, fold

It appears that I still do not understand C++'s `constexpr` well enough and come across weird aspects almost every day. Here I would like to ask about one specifically:

```
struct Part1 {
    static constexpr int size = 10;
};
struct Part2 {
    static constexpr int size = 24;
};

template<class ... Part>
struct Assembly {
    // this does not compile ...
    // static constexpr int sizeDirect = (... + Part::size);

    // this works, Assembly<Part1, Part2>::sizeFromFct is 34
    static constexpr int sumUp() { return (... + Part::size); }
    static constexpr int sizeFromFct = sumUp();
};
```

I am testing with MSVC 2017 in conformant mode (/permissive-), and of course C++17.

Why does the first version not compile but the second one does? Can `sizeDirect` be made to work with some syntax tweak?

Comment: Compiles on both clang and gcc, likely msvc bug: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7C26cu

Comment: It compiles in VS2019 so I suggest you upgrade.